# Do not forward property of Exchange EmailMessage - where can I find it?

Tags: c#, email, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I need to find out, whether **Exchange EmailMessage** is marked as **Do not forward**. **Which property should I look for?**

Here is documentation of [class EmailMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/exchange-server-api/aa567229(v%3Dexchg.150)).

This flag can be seet up in Outlook for example:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you work with email messages in transport pipeline, you find this information in superior [MailItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/exchange-server-api/aa581246(v%3Dexchg.150)) object. In properties you will find property *Microsoft.Exchange.RightsManagement.DecryptionTokenRecipient* indicating which user has permission to decrypt the message.

If you work with EWS look at [MailItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.item?view=exchange-ews-api) and its extended properties (not tested).

Answer (score 0):

See `MailItem`.[Permission](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.permission) / [PermissionService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.permissionservice) / [PermissionTemplateGuid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.permissiontemplateguid).

Comment: This is taken Office VBA reference. It is not related to EmailMessage I described.